# Dim a display with a raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, screen, light, kodi

I'm using the Pi3 and the last jessie-lite OS, and  I want to manage the brightness of the screen like Kodi does with the dim screensaver. 
After some google searching I found some tips but nothing works.
I'll be using an external light sensor and I want to manage the brightness proportionally at the value sent by the light sensor.
For the moment, I develop in Python2.7 but the issue can use another language or by shell.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ideally what you want would have been for the Kodi json api to support setting the screensaver, from what I understand it doesn't.
that said if your familiar with Python, and I'm not, you can develop a plug in that opens a socket (or communicates otherwise) with your program running on your pi, because from what I understand plugins have the ability to set the screensaver.

in other words, make a plug in that sends and receives message to and from the pi.

this is not really an answer because im not familiar with creating Kodi plugins, but I know it's possible because there are other plugins that do it...

Comment: Thank for your answer.
I don't want to develop Kodi plugins or something like that, I just want to know how to use the screen saver module to dim brightness in an app I am building... Let me explain, I installed Kodi on my Pi3 and after 3 minutes of inactivity the screen dims/fades to the black (display still on but light is dimmed to 10% or somewhere close). I want to use this feature outside of Kodi in my own python, shell, .. script.

Comment: what do you mean by screen saver module? there are screen saver add ons, where at least one is pre built into the Kodi install,, but you can add or remove screen saver add-ons at will. and unless the author of the addon provides a way to remotely control that screen saver add on then you will not be able to control the screen saver or it's settings. therefore afaik, the only way to control the screen saver functions is how I described it previously.